# Create Java class from WSDL

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to create a Java class from WSDL with maven cxf-codegen-plugin, but when I try to do it, it just shows an error and no generated classes.

I can't understand why I have this error, my pom file looks okay to me.

My `pom.xml` looks like

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-hc</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/CurrentTimeService.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>jaxb/try/*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/jaxb-try.episode</episodeFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>jaxb-generate-try</id>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>jaxb/try/*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/jaxb-try.episode</episodeFile>
                        <generatePackage>q1.q2</generatePackage>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>jaxb-generate-try_1</id>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>jaxb/try2/*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/jaxb-try2.episode</episodeFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>jaxb-generate-try2</id>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <catalog>src/main/resources/jaxb/catalog.xml</catalog>
                <catalogResolver>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.resolver.tools.ClasspathCatalogResolver</catalogResolver>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I build the project with Maven, I see the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.3:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project WebServicesTest: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.2.6/jaxb-xjc-2.2.6.jar!/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 86; columnNumber: 48; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xjc:globalJavaType' to a(n) 'group' component.
```

Comment: 'xjc:globalJavaType' seems to be JAXB issue, if that helps....

Comment: POM doesn't look ok _to me_... you have two different CXF versions, 2.7.3 and 2.5.1. Also, provide WSDL and XSD files.

Comment: With both 2.7.3 versions the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this post:

[Cannot resolve the name 'xjc:globalJavaType' in jaxb-xjc-2.2.5-2.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373733/cannot-resolve-the-name-xjcglobaljavatype-in-jaxb-xjc-2-2-5-2-jar)

You may have non-Latin characters in the path to your local Maven repo.  Try changing your settings.xml to set the  to some other directory containing only Latin characters and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change my repo location

Comment: Great, changing to Latin characters in maven local repository helps!
Thank you!